# Ordered list number style position

Tags: html, list

I have an ordered list:

```
<ol>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ol>
```

How do I position numbers in the vertical center of li items?

Currently they are in the top.

http://jsfiddle.net/xuZEb/6/

Thank you!

Comment: Are the ```<li>```s all one line long?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `line-height` to the same value you set `height` (`50px` in your example):

```
ol li {
    height: 50px;
    background:#eee;
    border: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HcDFY/1/